# Why do I have less than line voltage at a switch box?

Tags: switch, ceiling-fan

at the breaker I have 120 volts but I only measure 20 volts between either the black or the white and ground at the switch itself. Between the black and the white I have zero voltage.
Any idea what the problem might be ... the switch controls a ceiling fan.

Comment: Is that the only cable running into the switch box?  Does the ceiling fan work properly?

Comment: If neither the black or white has 120 volts to ground at the switch, then you may have 100 volts on the "ground" at the switch!

Answer (score 1):

You appear to have a bad connection in the ground wire somewhere.

With a standard switch loop, the Code requires the white wire in a 2 wire cable to be connected to the hot feed and be permanently re-identified as an ungrounded conductor. Most electricians just use some black electrical tape to re-identify the hot feed to the switch. Personally I like blue in this case as it is not used in a normal residential install so it stands out.

So, with the switch closed (on) you should not get any voltage between the white wire and the black. You should then get 120 volts from either the black or white wires to the ground wire. With the switch open (off) you should read 120 volts between these wires and 120 volts from the white to the ground wire.

You should re-identify the white wire as any color but white or green. Then look for a bad connection on the ground wire.

Good luck and stay safe!

Answer (score -1):

Look for somewhere the neutral (white wire) and the hot (black wire) may be stripped and touching each other, or crushed together (like in a staple that is driven too tight or a connector going into a box that is clamped too tight and marring the cable sheathing).

Getting light voltage from the neutral is your prime suspect in a marred wired situation. The fact that the neutral & hot both are showing the same voltage, I suspect they are touching each other.

Should have kicked the breaker, but sometimes, rarely, things are so perfectly wrong that breakers may not work like they should.

Comment: I'm actually wondering if he's got an open ground in a switch loop situation...

Comment: There is no neutral in a standard switch loop.